# My CSS class not working when appending from JS? (fcc wikipedia project)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the Wikipedia search engine API Project i'v been working on --> https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/full/zPxQob/

i append the search results to the `ul` (`id="result"`). I use this code:

```
$("#result").append("</li><a href='"+data[3][i]+"'<div class='presentDiv'><h5 class='present'>"+data[1][i]+"</h5><h5 class='desc'>"+data[2][i]+"</h5></div></a></li>")
```

Now if you go to search something, it pushes the description, link, and title but for some reason none of my class work. How can i get them to work?

Comment: Your leading li tag is wrong, which is going to mess up how your html is appended and probably what is causing the issue. Otherwise you are going to need to provide the css that you are using

Comment: I fixed the ```li``` tag, but how do i fix my classes? When i append shouldn't they apply? ```presentDiv``` , ```present``` , ```desc``` . Sorry i have to go, ill respond to any replies in the morning. Any and all are welcome.

Comment: your div is inside the anchor tag i mean in attribute fields of anchor tag

Comment: So what do i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may work small change i.e, closing anchor tag before div opens

```
$("#result").append("</li><a href='"+data[3][i]+"'><div class='presentDiv'><h5 class='present'>"+data[1][i]+"</h5><h5 class='desc'>"+data[2][i]+"</h5></div></a></li>")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked :D .  Also why is my question getting 4 dislikes? Did i do something wrong?